# No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111 - Map interface method to jsonb as you do in a domain class with @Entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

it is possible to map an interface method with type jsonb just as it is done in a class with `@Entity`.

In the example below it works fine, I have a column in postgres of type jsonb with the data `[1,2,3,4]`.

**Ex1:**

```
@Entity
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
@Getter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    private Set<Integer> blockedPlates;
}
```

But when creating an interface with a different projection than the domain class, I can't map the `getBlockedPlates()` method. Is there a way or not possible with interface?

**Ex2**

```
public interface ICarProjection {

    public Integer getCodeCar();
    public String getNameCar();
    public Set<Integer> getBlockedPlates();
    public Integer getYearCar();
}


@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "select f.id as codeCar,"
                   +" f.name as nameCar,"
                   +" f.blocked_plates as blockedPlates,"
                   +" f.year as yearCar"
                   +" from car f", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<ICarProjection> find();
}


Error: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the property for your database in configuration?

Something like

```
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
```